# How to wait for return of a function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a method which is returning a value and I'm assigning the return value to a variable. the function returns proper value but the variable is not set with the return value. But if I set `this.size` inside the function I get proper value. I'm calling `this.searchData` function from many functions, So I cannot do this(in this case I will have to use multi `if` statements), So is there any way to get the return value from the function. I thought to use `timeout` is there any other way around?

```
searchSize(event): void {
    this.sizes = this.searchData(event, AppConsts.size);
}

searchData(event, property): any {

    this._serviceProxy.getProperties(
        property,
        event.query,
        event.query
    ).subscribe((result) => {

        console.log(result.items);
        return result.items;
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) <-- JavaScript, but the exact same principle applies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cleaner simpler code, you could also use the async/await syntax. 
You have to convert your observable to a promise, and then you can await the result:

```
import * as rx  from 'rxjs'
class ListResultDtoOfPropertyDTO{
    items: any[]
}
class Test {
    sizes: any[];
    _serviceProxy : {
        getProperties() : rx.Observable<ListResultDtoOfPropertyDTO>
    }
    async searchSize(event): Promise<void> {
        this.sizes = await this.searchData(event);
    }

    async searchData(event): Promise<any[]> {
        var result = await this._serviceProxy.getProperties()
            .toPromise()

        console.log(result.items);
        return result.items;
    }
}
```

Explanations:

Typescript allow a nicer syntax around waiting for results from a Promise. The syntax does not apply to Observables (hopefully in the future it will), we can however convert the Observable to a promise in this case. For more information about async/await syntax, have a look [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/async-await.html)

Comment: Since i did not have the code of getProperties, guessing from your usage, i assumed getProperties returned an Obserable<{items: any[]}> (or something similar)

Comment: getProperties retruns Observable<ListResultDtoOfPropertyDTO>

Comment: In that case are you sure your original code compiles ? If `getProperties` returns an `Observable<ListResultDtoOfPropertyDTO>` then the `result` in subscribe would be of type `ListResultDtoOfPropertyDTO`, so if `ListResultDtoOfPropertyDTO` doesn't have `items` it should not have compiled. If `ListResultDtoOfPropertyDTO` has `items`  then toPromise would return a `Promise<ListResultDtoOfPropertyDTO>` and after the await the result should have an 'items' property. I will post a full example shortly

Comment: Thanks, Could you please explain your answer, it will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> How to wait for return of a function in TypeScript?

## Step 1

return the observable

```
 return this._serviceProxy.getProperties( // note : return
        property,
        event.query,
        event.query
    ).subscribe((result) => {

        console.log(result.items);
        return result.items;
    });
}
```

## Step 2

`subscribe` to the returned value e.g.

`searchData(something).subscribe`

Comment: didn't get step 2